# fill missing elements in each row in a R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

i have a csv file imported as data.frame, the problem is that each row must have 4 elements (4 columns), and some of them could have different number of elements, i mean something like:

```
ID  col1 col2 col3 col4
id1  dA  dB    dC   dD
id2  aA  aB    aC   aD
id3  mA  mB    mC
id4  xA  xB    xC   XD
```

I'm using tidyr, and when I import the data it fill each missing element with NA, in this case the id3 at the col4.

```
id3  mA  mB    mC NA
```

I want to fix all the row that have less than 4 elements in each row (like id3), just to add in the missing element a unclassified (UNC) something like:

```
ID  col1 col2 col3 col4
id1  dA  dB    dC   dD
id2  aA  aB    aC   aD
id3  mA  mB    mC  UNC
id4  xA  xB    xC   XD
```

Well this is my code:

```
df <- read.csv("file.csv", comment.char = "#", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

#add the id as row name:
rownames(df) <- paste("id", 1:nrow(df), sep = "")

# eliminate some elements of the data frame 
df[, 2:ncol(df)] <- NULL

# add a name of each column and split elements based in ";" character 
#at this point the "df" has a single column named "old_name":

df <- df %>% tidyr::separate(old_name, c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), sep = ";", extra="drop")
```

any suggestion !!!

thanks so much

Comment: Based on your code, you have a single column that you want to split up.  IN the data showed, there are 4 columns.  which one is correct

Comment: Please provide valid code; your `""col4` is a syntax/parsing error. (I know I can edit it just as easily, but ... I don't want to mask problems you might have and not know it, nor introduce other errors/differences if I infer incorrectly.)

Comment: `dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(a) if (is.character(a)) replace(a, is.na(a), "UNC") else a)`?

Comment: so sorry by the error in the syntax, it is "col4" instead ""col4 ... thanks so much !

Comment: wouldn't this directly work? `df[is.na(df)] <- 'UNC'`

Comment: hi, it works well, jut i would like to know a different option with R base, but it is ok .... thanks so much !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, ~ replace(., is.na(.), "UNC"))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
i1 <- sapply(df1, is.character)
df1[i1][is.na(df1[i1])] <- "UNC"
```

Comment: thanks so much, it works well with R base.  One more question, if I use R base or dplyr for this line:   df <- df %>% tidyr::separate(old_name, c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), sep = ";", extra="drop") how it could be ?? I ask because with this method it give me an warning, so I will like to use an other method ...... Thanks so much !!!

Comment: @abraham not clear whether the warning is a friendly one or not